# Making python wait before running an external program for the second time without a for loop

Tags: python, windows, cmd, marc

I am using VisualDoc to iterate the material properties in a finite element software (MSC MARC). 
The problem I am having is that VisualDoc executes multiple windows of the FEM simulation at once and I need the FEM program to execute one run at a time.

In visual doc the MARC program is called as follows: a cmd batch file is called which opens a python script which opens the MARC simulation. (I tried multiple ways of calling MARC from VisualDOC and this was the only way that worked well)

First I tried to set the MARC software to non-batch mode, but I cannot find the settings to do that.

At the moment I'm trying to write a python script that uses 
subprocess.Popen and it's accompanying wait() function, but I manually asked Python to run again while the first MARC run was still executing and it still opened a second MARC simulation. Is there a way to force Python to wait for the program to finish executing before it opens the next run?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["procedure.proc"], shell = True)
p.wait()
```

I thought of trying to use cmd for the same effect, but since python opens the MARC program I think it is most probably better to code the wait into python. Am I right in this assumption or would it be better to enforce the wait through cmd?

The current cmd code is as follows:

```
CD C:\INTERFACEMARC\loop
openmarc.py
```

**Note:**
I am unable to use a for loop as the python script should open the MARC program only once in order to work with my VisualDoc optimization code.

At the moment the code for opening MARC looks as follows, but as far as I understand this does not prevent the python script from executing a second time while MARC is still running (based on my manual test).

Comment: `Popen` with `shell=True` is running `cmd /c "procedure.proc"`. cmd should wait for that command to exit, but only if it can, i.e. if `ShellExecuteEx` returns a handle to a process for `procedure.proc`. In Python, `p.wait()` in turn waits for cmd to exit. What's the purpose of using Python to run `procedure.proc` instead of simply running it in your batch script?

Comment: BTW, for `Popen` don't use a list of arguments with `shell=True`. Only use an argument list with the default `shell=False`.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply!

Comment: I actually got the program working. It seems that VisualDOC waits for the python script to finish running before moving on to the next step in the iterative process, so when I used the Popen code along with VisualDOC; Python waits for MARC to finish running before it closes and in doing so it forces the VisualDOC optimization to open only one MARC window at a time. I tried running the batch script directly from cmd, but I couldn't get it working in VisualDOC.

Comment: Your `Popen` command executes via cmd, which in turn runs procedure.proc via the system shell function `ShellExecuteEx`. Thus .proc must be a registered file type on your system. You should be able to replace openmarc.py with procedure.proc in your batch script -- unless openmarc.py does something else that you're not showing. To avoid waiting on procedure.proc when run in cmd's batch mode, use `start procedure.proc`.